# Convert ArrayString to Array android

Tags: java, android

How can I convert this array string

```
String x = "[1000000062,1000000095,1000000058,1000000400]" ;
```

to Array of type array android

for e.g.

```
int[] ids = {1000000062,1000000095,1000000058,1000000400} ;
```

Comment: You mean you want to convert your String array to an int array, right? Because an 'Array of type array' makes no sense.

Comment: How about reading up on 'parse string to int', 'using loops'. That should do it :)

Comment: i have a string x in array format. i want to convert it to array type int[] ids.

Comment: You have a string *that contains JSON representing an array of ints*. Use the JSON parsing classes. Done.

Comment: what do you mean by json parsing classes ?

Comment: See my answer below using `JSONArray`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
String []aaaa = "[1000000062,1000000095,1000000058,1000000400]".replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
    int aa[] = new int[aaaa.length];
    for(int i=0; i<aa.length; i++){
        aa[i] = Integer.parseInt(aaaa[i]);
    }
```

Comment: While this works ... it's completely re-inventing the wheel. Android includes JSON parsing classes.

Answer (score 1):

The string you show is JSON; specifically an array of integers.

Android includes classes for parsing JSON:

[JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) for example:

```
String x = "[1000000062,1000000095,1000000058,1000000400]" ;
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(x);
int iArray[] = new int[jArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) { 
    iArray[i] = jArray.getInt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way.

```
    String x = "[1000000062,1000000095,1000000058,1000000400]";
    String[] arr=x.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","").split(","); // remove `[` and `]` 
                                                         and split x by `,'
    int[] intArr=new int[arr.length]; // create int[] in arr size
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        intArr[i]=Integer.parseInt(arr[i]) ; // convert arr[] to int array
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a simple solution:

```
String x = "[1000000062,1000000095,1000000058,1000000400]" ;
String xArray[]=x.split("\\[|\\]|,");
int[] ids=new int[xArray.length];
int i=0;
for(String val:xArray){          
    if(val.matches("\\d+")){
       ids[i++]=Integer.parseInt(val);
    }
}
```